# TBB won't affect performance no matter the configurations

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, g++, tbb

I've noticed that no matter what configurations are provided to a paralllel program i've written, TBB does not affect performance neither in a positive or a negative way.
By configurations, I mean:

1. Number of threads
2. Input size (of an array)
3. grainsize argument at `tbb::parallel_for`
4. The number of times the same process is repeated.

It is like the performance is exactly the same as a sequencial program.

I have:

1. Linked with `g++`, using `-ltbb`
2. Used `tbb::task_scheduler_init`, and it doesn't get out of scope since the initialization takes place at the main function.
3. Used `tbb::parallel_for` with various grainsizes

I am not using locks, the only components used from TBB are `tbb::task_scheduler_init` and `tbb::parallel_for`.

The code where `tbb::parallel_for` is used looks something like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
    //parallel_for invocation.
    //The lambda passed at parallel_for
    //does some mathematical computations
    //(potentially costly).

    if it isn't the last iteration of the loop then
        //Calls costly function.
}
```

Could the problem be that `tbb::task_scheduler_init` is depracated? Since I do get a warning message about it, but I've tried `tbb::task_arena` as well, but nothing changes.

I've tried experimenting with almost anything that can be configured, just to see an effect on performance. How is it possible, that given a certain input, no matter what the configurations, the program no matter how many times I run it, the running time is always fixed to approximately say 10 seconds? This just gives a feeling that it is like TBB does no parallelization

Comment: Which code do you parallelize? If there is a giant lock in the code, then it is normal that it runs in sequential. Hard to say without the code. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The code is still not reproducible (nor complete) and not very useful. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Note that function of library you may call can use locks even if you do not explicitly use locks. There are many possible source of slowdown that can cause hidden synchronizations like false sharing for example. Please test with a function calling Sleep and check the resulting time.